# Task 'assemble' not found in root project while running from Bamboo

Tags: android, gradle, build, bamboo, assemble

The project runs from my AndroidStudio, but when I try to run it from my build machine I get this error:

```
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    * What went wrong:
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'VMOD-VAD-VRANDROID'.
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    * Try:
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    BUILD FAILED
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    
30-Jun-2017 12:04:27    Total time: 53.372 secs
```

Now I don't understand what `assemble` is, where can I find it and how to fix this?

I have another bamboo project that works, and searched for assemble in it, but found nothing, Can someone explain to me what that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the following 2 files in gitignore:

```
gradlew.bat
settings.gradle
```